# Celery multi not working as expected

Tags: celery, celery-task, celeryd

I have this my project folder structure

```
api
    -- __init__.py
    --jobs/
        -- __init__.py
        -- celery.py
        -- celeyconfig.py
        -- tasks.py
    --api_helpers/
    --views/
```

tasks has a task called `ExamineColumns`

I launch the worker using `celery worker -A api.jobs  --loglevel=Info`

It works fine and I can run the tasks.

This is the ourput of celery examine command

```
$ celery inspect registered
-> ranjith-ThinkPad-T420: OK
    * ExamineColumns
    * celery.backend_cleanup
    * celery.chain
    * celery.chord
    * celery.chord_unlock
    * celery.chunks
    * celery.group
    * celery.map
    * celery.starmap
```

But when I try the multi mode it simply does not work. I am trying to run by running

```
celery multi start w1 -c3 -A api.jobs  --loglevel=Info
```

But it does not start at all.

```
$ celery inspect registered
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
```

I am not sure why it is not working

Answer (score 3):

You can try to run as:

```
/usr/bin/celery multi start w1 w2 --uid=www --loglevel=INFO --pidfile=/var/run/%n.pid --logfile=/var/log/%n.log --quiet
```

`--uid` must be user/group from your server. Not recommended use *root*

`--quiet` will not output data to console

`%n.log` will replace itself on w1.log and w2.log

---

For checking you can use `ps uax | grep celery` Result will be as so:

```
www ... /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery.bin.celeryd -n w1.domain.ru --loglevel=DEBUG --logfile=/var/log/w1.log --pidfile=/var/run/w1.pid
www ... /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -m celery.bin.celeryd -n w2.domain.ru --loglevel=DEBUG --logfile=/var/log/w2.log --pidfile=/var/run/w2.pid
```

Comment: How do I give the --app argument. Just append to the command?

Comment: It seems I not knew about `--app argument` But if you want to run celery for your project you must it run from folder that included  config file of celery. The config of celery should have option `CELERY_IMPORTS=("path_to_app.tasks",)` See http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=celery_imports#celery-imports

Comment: Is it possible to run the multi start command not as a daemon?

Comment: @tzenderman Yes, but It seems I don't understood you. Please, give me  more details your's task.

Comment: @AbbasovAlexander So, I run celery using supervisord. I wasn't able to find a way to run `celery multi start` without daemonizing the process. For it to be able to work correctly with supervisord, the process cannot be run as a daemon.